# Hostname doesn't resolve to DNS server IP address

Tags: dns, ip, dynamic-dns

I have a home server connected to  a router which set to use a DDNS with an integreated provider pointing to a no-ip DNS server. After a power outage my domain can't be reached any longer. Checking the IP address with

```
dig +short pacolola.net
```

...I get the address `188.151.207.219`. According to the router's Public IPv4 Address and No-IP's user pages it should be `188.151.218.129`. Using the later address shows the page content and the server's internal IP address is also working.

I've attempted to restart the network with `sudo service networking restart` and various DNS cache reset commands without success.

How do I resolve the hostname to the IP address which the DNS servers are using? Is this a DNS problem laying with no-ip <=> router or SLL or something on the server? What diagnostic tools are valid in this case?

Comment: Looks like whatever updates DDNS didn't update it correctly.  Without knowing some details on how you have that set up, there's not much we can help with.

Comment: I've added to the question that the router has an integrated provider to no-ip. I used to run the DUC (Dynamic Update Client) on an other instance but found that unstable and unnecessary as there's the integrated provider.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to make sure that your DDNS updater runs. No-IP's DDNS updater for Linux/Unix is `/usr/local/bin/noip2`. [See its installation instructions here.](https://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/installing-the-linux-dynamic-update-client/)

The install instructions web page refers to the README file in the software package for instructions on how to make the updater start automatically:

> HOW TO START THE CLIENT
>
> The noip2 executable can be run by typing /usr/local/bin/noip2
>
> If you want it to run automatically when the machine is booted, then
> place the following script in your startup directory. (/etc/init.d/rcX.d
> or /sbin/init.d/rcX.d or ???)

```
#######################################################
#! /bin/sh
# . /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions  # uncomment/modify for your killproc
case "$1" in
    start)
    echo "Starting noip2."
    /usr/local/bin/noip2
    ;;
    stop)
    echo -n "Shutting down noip2."
    killproc -TERM /usr/local/bin/noip2
    ;;
    *)
    echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop}"
    exit 1
esac
exit 0
#######################################################
```

> Where the 'X' in rcX.d is the value obtained by running the
> following command
>
> grep initdefault /etc/inittab | awk -F: '{print $2}'
>
> Killproc can be downloaded from ftp://ftp.suse.com/pub/projects/init
> Alternatively, you can uncomment the line after #! /bin/sh
>
> If you have a recent RedHat version, you may want to use the startup script
> supplied by another user.  It's in this package called redhat.noip.sh
> It may need some modification for your system.
>
> There is a startup script for Debian called debian.noip2.sh.
> It also has been supplied by another user and is rumored to fail in some
> situations.
>
> Another user has supplied a proceedure to follow for MAc OS X auto startup.
> It's called mac.osx.startup.  Mac users may wish to read that file.

However, **as is, these Unix/Linux instructions will only work on systems with classic SysVinit start-up script scheme.** Modern Linux systems can have various dependency-based systems for starting services, which have extra requirements that are not covered by these instructions.

For example, even RHEL 6 would require the script to have some specifically-formatted comment lines to identify the other services the script depends on. And on systems with `systemd`, placing the script just into `/etc/init.d/rcX.d` might not work, as `systemd`'s SysVinit compatibility system expects the scripts to be located in `/etc/init.d`, and also have those dependency-identifying comments, the same as with RHEL 6 and above.

Even the `redhat.noip.sh` example script in the package is obsolete: the special comments in it are incomplete for the modern dependency-based start-up schemes:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# chkconfig: 345 99 80
# description: Starts and stops the no-ip.com Dynamic dns client daemon
#
# pidfile: /var/run/noipd.pid
#
```

It might have worked with RHEL 5.x and older, but not with RHEL 7.x and newer. (For RHEL 6.x, the old form *might* have been acceptable, but the new format was already recommended at that point.) They would require an additional comment block immediately after the one above, like this:

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:             noip2
# Required-Start:       $local_fs $network
# Required-Stop:        $local_fs $network
# Default-Start:
# Default-Stop:
# Short-Description:    Starts and stops noip2
# Description:          Starts and stops the no-ip.com Dynamic dns client daemon
### END INIT INFO
```

But for `systemd`-based Linux distributions, it would be simpler to omit the script altogether and use a native systemd `.service` file, e.g. `/etc/systemd/system/noip2.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=no-ip.com Dynamic dns client daemon
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/noip2

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

(For `systemd` purists: there did not seem to be an option that would stop `noip2` from forking into the background, so it looks like using a service with `Type=simple` is not possible at the time of this writing.)

So if you have just followed No-IP.com's installation instructions without also using your own initiative, it is very likely that the updater was only run from the point you started it manually until the next time you rebooted the server. But if the external IP address did not change, you might have been none the wiser... until now, when you get a different IP address from before.

Comment: for your detailed explanation. If it wasn't for the fact that the router is using an integrated provider to no-ip the this would have been the accepted answer. I apologize for not pointing this out previously.

Comment: Hmm... perhaps no-ip.com has changed something since the router's integrated DDNS functionality was programmed, and so the integrated provider info could now be outdated. Does the router have firmware updates available? If there are, updated firmware might include updated DDNS provider settings.

Comment: There wasn't a fireware update on the Sagem DM1901718003217 router so I guess I'll have to ask the ISP to check for an upstate. I'm suspecting they perform an OTA (Over The Air) update on their side.
I did a Gateway Update update and disabled/enabled the DDNS settings but with no effect. I'm wondering if there was a hardware component which fried by the electricity outage? The server's electricity supply had to be changed for instance.

Comment: The DDNS IP at no-ip and the public IP on the router are the same which should mean that the integrated provider is working, no?

Comment: The problem has (temporarily?) been resolved by setting the website hostname IP to the same as the DDNS on the account pages. I'm not quite on board why the website IP address wouldn't change with the DDNS but will investigate further. I also found out that servervault is a better forum for related questions.

Comment: You're entirely correct: if the public IP matches what no-ip's user page says, then the provider is working. Maybe something was caching the old DNS record (perhaps the DNS server at your internet provider?) and it took a while for the cached entry to expire? Or maybe you had the old address in `/etc/hosts`?

Comment: The `hosts` file is pointing to the correct local IP address so maybe the fault was in the DNS record as you were suggesting. 
What I did now is create a group for the website, ftp... and DDNS hostnames and hope now that when the DDNS IP changes that the other ones will as well.